# Quantile regression analyzing the conditional quantiles of one of the regressors?

Tags: regression, econometrics, quantiles, quantile-regression, estimators

Given response $Y_t$ and predictor $X_t$, we can use OLS to analyze the conditional mean; $E[Y_t | X]$. Quantile regression can be used to analyze the conditional quantile function; $Q(Y_t(\tau)|X)$. Specifically;

$$(1) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,Q(Y_t(\tau)|X) = a(\tau) + b(\tau)X_t + e_t$$

In this one variable case, we can easily look at the conditional quantile function of $X_t$ by simply estimating:

$$(2) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,Q(X_t(\tau)|Y) = \alpha(\tau) + \beta(\tau)Y_t + e_t$$

However, consider the following specification:

$$(3) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,Q(Y_t(\tau)|X,Z) = a(\tau) + b(\tau)X_t + c(\tau)Z_t + e_t$$

In this case, I can't see a way to do something similar to what I did in $(2)$.

*My question is*: **Can I do something similar to what I'm proposing in (4), where I analyze the response, $Y_t$, with respect to the predictor $Z_t$ as well as the *conditional quantiles* of the predictor $X_t$?**

$$(4) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,Y_t = \alpha(\tau) + \beta(\tau)Q(X_t(\tau)|Y,Z) + \gamma(\tau)Z_t + e_t$$

(excuse poor notation)

Comment: Do you mean to condition $X_t$ on $Y_t$ as well ($\xi_\alpha(X_t \mid Z_t)$ versus $\xi_\alpha(X_t \mid Y_t, Z_t)$, where $\xi_\alpha$ denotes the $\alpha$-th quantile)? That makes the computed conditional quantiles endogenous.

Answer (score 2):

This does not make sense to me. The point of regression is to use the variation in covariates ($x$ variables) to explain the variation in some variable of interest ($y$). If you have no variability in a covariate, it isn’t helping to accomplish that goal.

What you might find interesting is to fit a quantile regression and then determine the conditional quantile $\tau$ at quantile $\tau$ of some covariate, but this is separate from estimating the model parameters.